# Change Word Save Directory

Tags: c#, save, office-interop

I am using a Win Form to open a word doc, I then make changes and need to save it as a different file name and different location.  How could I programatically change the 'default' location that opens when I click File-Save As in Word?  I am not wanting to hardcode one location as the 'new' location changes based on what word doc I actually opened.  I looked at the SaveFileDialog but it seems to me that just opens the Dialog of where to save.

Comment: Aye you using Automation, or just opening WinWord.exe?

Comment: Using automation to open winword -- then ideally would like to click file then save as and code in a save location based off of the file that was opened.
Does that help clarify?